# Scraping a table using td instead of nth-child

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm scraping the table located on this page: [Whale Alert Whale Limits](https://whale-alert.io/whales)

The elements I'm trying to scrape are Currency, Known, and Unknown. I'm using the following function:

```
 const currencyTable = await page.evaluate(() => 
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr'), (e) => ({
        currency: e.querySelector('i').innerText,
        Know: e.querySelector(':nth-child(2)').innerText,
        Unknown: e.querySelector(':nth-child(3)').innerText,
    }))
);
```

That returns me the following array of objects:

```
[{"currency":"BTC","Know":"$20,000,000","Unknown":"$100,000,000"},
{"currency":"USD Stable Transfer ","Know":"","Unknown":"$200,000,000"},
{"currency":"USD Stable Mint/Burn ","Know":"","Unknown":"NA"}, 
{"currency":"ETH","Know":"$20,000,000","Unknown":"$100,000,000"}, 
{"currency":"XRP","Know":"$10,000,000","Unknown":"$50,000,000"}, 
{"currency":"EOS","Know":"$5,000,000","Unknown":"$10,000,000"}, 
{"currency":"XLM","Know":"$5,000,000","Unknown":"$10,000,000"}, 
{"currency":"ERC20","Know":"$5,000,000","Unknown":"$20,00,000"}, 
{"currency":"NEO","Know":"$1,000,000","Unknown":"$5,000,000"}, 
{"currency":"TRX","Know":"$5,000,000","Unknown":"$20,000,000"}, 
{"currency":"XTZ","Know":"$2,500,000","Unknown":"$10,000,000"}, 
{"currency":"ICX","Know":"$1,000,000","Unknown":"$5,000,000"}, 
{"currency":"HIVE","Know":"$1,000,000","Unknown":"$5,000,000"}, 
{"currency":"STEEM","Know":"$1,000,000","Unknown":"$5,000,000"}, 
{"currency":"Scams","Know":"$25,000","Unknown":"NA"}, 
{"currency":"Donations","Know":"$1,000,000","Unknown":"NA"}]
```

It is close enough, but it has problems with these two currencies: **USD Stable Transfer** and
**USD Stable Mint/Burn** The values are not ok:
[image]

I've decided to use `querySelector(':nth-child(2)')` because if I try to use:

```js
Know: e.querySelector('td').innerText,
Unknown: e.querySelector('td').innerText
```

I receive only the currency names. And if I change the number of the child the other currencies return wrong values.

I've tried to follow something similar that I can see in this thread: [Select the second table row of a table using puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55872007/select-the-second-table-row-of-a-table-using-puppeteer) but I get the data OK for the other currencies not for **USD Stable Transfer** and **USD Stable Mint/Burn**.

Comment: Just use `e.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').innerText` - in the failing cases it somehow identifies the `a` element as the second child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When scraping simple tables, stick to selecting by `<tr>` and `<td>` which makes no assumptions about what the `<td>`s might contain:

```js
const currencyTable = await page.evaluate(() => 
  [...document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr")].map(e => {
    const cells = e.querySelectorAll("td");
    return {
      currency: cells[0].textContent.trim(),
      Know: cells[1].textContent.trim(),
      Unknown: cells[2].textContent.trim(),
    };
  })
);
```

Also, you probably don't even need Puppeteer here. Using plain `fetch` and `cheerio` is much faster:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

fetch("<your URL>") // Node 18 or install node-fetch
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const rows = [...$("table tr")].slice(1).map((e, i) => {
      const cells = $(e).find("td");
      return {
        currency: $(cells[0]).text().trim(),
        Know: $(cells[1]).text().trim(),
        Unknown: $(cells[2]).text().trim(),
      };
    })
    console.table(rows);
  })
;
```